# How can I get dynamic content on my static home page

Tags: theme-development

Sorry for this but I am sure this is a duplicate question, but I have been searching, but I cannot find a suitable answer for this question. I hope you still can help.

I want to create a website with a few static pages, and a blog. Now on one of the static pages, the portfolio page, I want to have all of my work in boxes in a list. Just like you would have blog posts.

Now I not want to create a post for each of the work I have done, because it will mingle with the blog I guess. Is there another option on WP to have snippets of content, just as posts, which could be loaded into a page.

Or should I just create the whole portfolio page just as a big static page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create Custom Post Type, I've done it for the very first time using [this tutorial](http://thinkvitamin.com/code/create-your-first-wordpress-custom-post-type/).

Basically, you have to add "a few" lines to functions.php and then add your portfolio items as posts in new custom post type (it will be available in your admin panel).

I hope it helps :)

Comment: This is just what I need, great answer, great tutorial, and you have a great username. Accepted answer.